# Remover a linha de um CSV pela posição - PHP

Tags: php, csv

Olá.Tenho um formulário que gera um Arquivo CSV com os dados inseridos pelo usuário. Os dados salvos nesse csv são printados na tela onde é atribuido um número para cada linha (1,2,3...). Eu precisava que o usuário pudesse excluir alguma linha que ele quisesse por meio dessa numeração, eu estou tentando fazer por meio de um input, onde ele digita o número da linha e clica no botão "excluir". O que eu não consigo é fazer que a partir do clique do botão seja excluida apenas uma linha (a que tem o mesmo valor digitado pelo usuário), o código está apagando todas. Segue o código que tenho até o momento.

//Formulario e criação do CSV

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?php
if ($_POST){
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $telephone = $_POST["telefone"];
    $cargo = $_POST["cargo"];
    $setor = $_POST["setor"];

    $quantidadeLinhas = count($nome);
    $dados = "";
    $fileName = "dados.csv"; 

    for ($i=0; $i<$quantidadeLinhas; $i++) {
      $dados .= "$nome[$i],";
      $dados .= "$telephone[$i],";
      $dados .= "$cargo[$i],";
      $dados .= "$setor[$i]";
      $dados .= "\n"; 
     } 

   $fileHandle = fopen($fileName,"a+"); 
   fwrite($fileHandle,"$dados"); 
   fclose($fileHandle);
}
?>

<html>

 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

   <title>Formulário</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="adiciona.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="excluiLinha.js"></script>

   <style type="text/css" media="all">
    body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif }
    #tudo{ border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;width:570px;margin:0 auto }
    .bd_titulo{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    font-weight:bold
     }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
   <form method="post" name="frm_campo_dinamico" action="">
   <div id="tudo">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" width="100%">
  <tr><td colspan="4" class="bd_titulo">Formulário</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4" align="center"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Nome</td><td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Telefone</td><td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Cargo</td><td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Setor</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="linhas">
       <td>
        <input style="text-align:center" align="center" type="text" name="nome[]"/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id = "telefone" align="center" name="telefone[]" class = "telMask"/>
       </td>
       <td>
        <select name="cargo[]">
          <option>Selecione</option>
          <option value="Auxiliar">Auxiliar</option>
          <option value="Secretária">Secretária</option>
          <option value="Gerente">Gerente</option>           
        </select>
       </td>
       <td>
        <select name="setor[]">
                 <option>Selecione</option>
                 <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
                 <option value="Administrativo">Administrativo</option>            
        </select>
       </td> 
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
          <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="add.svg" border="0" /></a>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" colspan="0">
         <td align="right" colspan="4">
         <input type="submit" id="Salvar" value="Salvar" class = "gwt-Button" />
         </td>
        </tr>
      </tr> 
    </table>
   </form>
   </div>

  <hr width="1" size="1" color = "white">

   <div id="tudo">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" width="100%">
   <tr><td colspan="4" class="bd_titulo">Dados Salvos</td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="4" align="center"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Linha</td><td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Nome</td>td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Telefone</td><td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Cargo</td><td class="bd_titulo" align="center">Setor</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php $file = fopen('dados.csv','r'); $contando = 1; while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){echo $contando++."<br />";} ?></font></td>
      <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php $file = fopen('dados.csv','r'); while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){echo $line[0]."<br />";}?></font></td>
      <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php $file = fopen('dados.csv','r'); while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){echo $line[1]."<br />";}?></font></td>
      <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php $file = fopen('dados.csv','r'); while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){echo $line[2]."<br />";}?></font></td>
      <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php $file = fopen('dados.csv','r'); while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){echo $line[3]."<br />";}?></font></td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
   </div>

  <hr width="1" size="1" color = "white">

    <form method="post" name="salvos" action="">
   <div id="tudo">
     <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" width="100%">
     <tr><td colspan="4" class="bd_titulo">Excluir Linha</td></tr>
     <tr><td colspan="4" align="center"></td></tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="4">
      <font color="black">Linha:</font> 
      <input style="text-align:center" type="number" min = "1" name="deletar"/>
      <input type="submit" id="btnExcluir" value="Excluir" class = "gwt-Button"/>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
   </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

//para a tabela dinamica

```
$(function () {
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
  novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
  novoCampo.find("input").val("");
  novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
  });
});
```

//Ajax quando clica no botão de excluir

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnExcluir').click(function(){
    //Pega o valor a ser excluido
    var deletar = $("deletar").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deletarLinhas.php",
        data: deletar,
        success: function () {
            alert("Teste se tá enviando");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

//PHP que vai excluir a linha (Parte que não funciona)

```
<?php
$removerLinha = $_POST["deletar"];

$meuArray = Array();
$file = fopen("dados.csv", "r");

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
  $meuArray[] = $line;
}

fclose($file);

$remover = $removerLinha - 1;
$linhas = count(file("dados.csv"));
$limite = $linhas -1;

//verifica se o valor dado pelo usuário é menor ou igual ao numero de linhas do arquivo
if ($remover<=$limite){
 //remove
 unset($meuArray[$remover]);
 $meuArray = array_values($meuArray);
 //realinha
 var_dump($meuArray);
 //reescreve o arquivo sem a linha excluida
 $fileHandle = fopen("dados.csv","w"); 
 fwrite($fileHandle,$meuArray); 
 fclose($fileHandle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Não vejo como duplicata porque a minha pergunta se refere a retirada de uma linha especifica que pode estar no meio do arquivo, as respostas dadas nessa pergunta são para cortar o arquivo até uma determinada linha, não retirar uma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu arquivo php não conte as linhas do arquivo, já trate no for a linha que deseja remover.

> Exemplo

```
<?php

$removerLinha = $_POST["deletar"] - 1;

$meuArray = Array();
$file = fopen("dados.csv", "r");

$index = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
  if($index != $removerLinha) {
        $meuArray[] = implode(",", $line);
  }
  $index++;
}

fclose($file);

// apagando arquivo antigo
unlink("dados.csv");

// recriando arquivo sem a linha
   $fileHandle = fopen("dados.csv", "a+"); 
   fwrite($fileHandle, implode("\n", $meuArray)); 
   fclose($fileHandle);
```

E no seu ajax que envia a linha, lembre-se de especificar a propriedade *deletar*.

> Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnExcluir').click(function(){
    //Pega o valor a ser excluido
    var deletar = $("[name=\"deletar\"]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deletarLinhas.php",
        data: {deletar: deletar},
        success: function () {
            alert("Teste se tá enviando");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

E pronto, com isso já vai funciona ;)

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda. Então dessa maneira não funcionou, ele escreveu array em todas as linhas da primeira coluna do CSV. Vou editar o post e colocar como ficou, pelos comentários não tem como fixar imagem.

Comment: @Marie já coloquei a correção 

Comment: Agora ele exclui a linha, tipo se tinha 1,2,3,4 fica 1,2,3. Porém os dados somem, só aparece o número da linha e o restante fica em branco. Não sei mais o que fazer :(

Comment: @Marie veja se as aspas do implode no while estão corretas, como escrevi pelo celulaer... podem estar erradas...

Comment: @Marie arrumei as aspas, tente novamente.

Comment: Agora ele não está fazendo nada quando clico no botão excluir. Permanecem os mesmos dados de antes.

Comment: @Marie tentou apagar qual linha?

Comment: @Marie o $(“deletar”).val() é um id? Se for faltou o #

Comment: não, tá como name

Comment: @Marie editei a resposta...

Comment: permanece da mesma forma :/

Comment: @Marie coloca um alert no deletar e me diga o que ele imprimi..

Comment: Consegui resolver aqui. Era problema com o browser e realemente a captura do valor do numero tava errada, modifiquei para uma ID. Muito obrigada pela ajuda, sua solução deu certinho.

Comment: Aee!! que bom que funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Tente no lugar *unset($meuArray[$remover])* fazer o seguinte ***array_splice($meuArray, $remover , 1)***.